# Is there any 3D coordinate system that is periodic in two angles?

Tags: coordinate-systems, 3d

In spherical coordinates the angle $\varphi = \arctan y/x$ (or $\theta$, whichever [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Conventions) you prefer) is fully periodic, i.e. all values in the range $0$ to $2\pi$ are reached. However, the second angle, $\vartheta=\arctan \sqrt{x^2+y^2}/z$, is not periodic, ranging only from $0$ to $\pi$. Now I am wondering, is there also a coordinate system using two angles *both* of which have a periodic range? Or is there a proof that this is not possible?

Comment: Was there seriously a downvote for using the "wrong" [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Conventions) about the angles? Or is there a reason I can actually fix?

Answer (score 2):

The question uses both notational conventions and defintions in a nonstandard way:

1. The polar angle $\arctan(y/x)$ is usually denoted $\theta$, not $\varphi$.
2. The azimuthal angle $\arctan(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}/z)$ is normally denoted $\phi$, not $\vartheta$.
3. The word "periodic" describes any function or phenomenon that repeats itself at fixed intervals.  It is not correct to describe the azimuthal angle as "not periodic" because it ranges "only from $0$ to $\pi$" -- indeed that is fully periodic, and the period is $\pi$.

However, if for some reason you want to describe 3-dimensional space using two coordinates that have the *same* period, I suppose you could always just define a new coordinate, say $\psi$, by $\psi = 2\phi$.  Then both $\theta$ and $\psi$ would range between $0$ and $2\pi$, with points in the $xy$-plane corresponding to $\psi = \pi$ and points on the unit sphere at the "South pole" corresponding to $\psi = 2\pi$.  In this case $\psi$ would not really correspond to an angle measurement in a geometric sense, but it would have the mathematical properties that you are asking for.

Comment: Nonstandard? Maybe in pure Mathematics, in Physics this is [well established](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Conventions) that way... Maybe my question can benefit from some improvement nonetheless, obviously I'm not talking about periodic functions. Doubling the angle does of course not solve the problem. What I mean is an angular description that, for both angles, requires a full circle to describe all possible coordinates

Comment: @TobiasKienzler  $S^1 \times S^1$ is isomorphic to a torus, so I suppose if you had some natural way to partition $\mathbb R^3$ into toroidal surfaces you could then use two parameters $\theta$ and $\phi$ to locate points on those surfaces.

Comment: I am surprised to learn that Physicists use coordinates that way, but your point is taken. In any case, this is MSE, not http://physics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Now _that_ sounds more like an answer than the above. _Can_ $\mathbb R^3$ be partitioned into toroidal surfaces? I have to think about this some more, though probably there's be a singularity in the origin...

Comment: This answer uses definitions in a nonstandard and actually incorrect manner: "The polar angle $\arctan(y/x)$ is usually denoted $\theta$, not $\varphi$". Um, as the name suggests, the "polar angle" denotes the angle from the pole (north, by convention) or zenith. It is thus given by $\arctan(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}/z)$. And similarly for the "azimuthal angle".  Unless your convention is that your "pole" is along the x axis... which neither physicists nor mathematicians "conventionally" use, so your convention would be arguably doubly nonstandard.

Answer (score -3):

Didn't understand your question to be honest, but how about light with its electric field's plane of oscillation along plane x=y in normal cartesian system.
EDIT:
On second thoughts that won't even be periodic.
EDIT 2:- how about $\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}}=asint$